# Sequel to the Sefer " Laws of Daily Living "

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, pesukei-dezimra, bircas-krias-shema

There is a well known Sefer on Halacha called *Laws of Daily Living* by Rav Simcha Bunim Cohen , noted *Posek* and author. There is only one volume and the last topic is the laws of *פסוקי דזמרה*.

Any suggestions on an easy-to-read English *Halacha* *Sefer* that would act as sort of a sequel to his Sefer (i.e., a Sefer that starts off with the laws of *Birchos Krias Shema* ?)

Answer (score 1):

Of all the simple halacha books I read in English, the one I liked best an which best matches the level of *Laws of Daily Living* is [Shaarei Halachah by R Zeev Greenwald](http://amzn.com/1583304347)

If you want something more elaborate the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch is the real classic. In English there is an older edition from R Avraham Davis or [a much better edition from artscroll](http://amzn.com/1422611043) (also exists on iPad and Android)

There is also a recent book which was originally written for yeshiva students as a set of "all the practical laws you need to know": [Halacha 24/7/12](http://a.co/aYDijQs). It is remarkable in that it is both broad, highly accessible to everyone, incredibly practical and actually interesting to read. In a number of places the author show pragmatism by writing "Artscroll says X but basic halacha is Y". The goal of the author is to show halacha is not "[in the heaven or beyond the sea](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.30.12?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)" but instead very approachable. It does cover in detail the laws of prayer and of daily living.

Comment: I don't know about R' Davis's edition, but the ArtScroll translation lacks sources and differing opinions.

Comment: R Davis doesn't have comments or sources - it is a straight translation. Artscroll is a translation in the style of the Schottenstein gmara and brings additional sources from MB and Igrot Moshe. It doesn't pretend to be a comprehensive multi-sourced SA, rather an elucidation of the KSA. In that I think it does a good job but understand one might want more sources and different opinions